# Q: Selenium Stopped Working After Working Previously

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have been successfully running a script to read through a list of protein accession numbers and send it to a website to get its name. I realized using driver.close(); left chrome running as a process and ended up crashing eclipse. I switched to driver.quit(); and it was working fine until it got a DNS lookup error. After that eclipse has been running slow and now when I run the code it opens the webpage, gets through to pressing search, and doesn't send any keys or press any buttons. Other projects work fine still. I tried restarting several times and clearing the .history folder but neither of those have fixed the problem.

Has anyone had this problem or know how to correct it?

Code:

```
package ncbi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;//and all other necessary imports
public class NameGetter {
    static int z = 0;
    static String b;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        nameFromNCBI();

    }

private static void nameFromNCBI() throws IOException { 
    String names;
    String names2;
    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;

    File file = new File("subjectNames4.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    while (a < 26405) {
    b = Integer.toString(z);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("X:\\FilePath" + b + ".txt"));  //this is to handle errors to load a new file from the line it left off from
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        while ((names = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "X:\\Java\\Selenium\\chromeAPI\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/");
            WebElement searchTerm = driver.findElement(By.id("term"));
            searchTerm.sendKeys(names);
            WebElement press = driver.findElement(By.id("search"));
            press.click();
            WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 600)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("dblinks")));
            WebElement theName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maincontent']/div/div[5]/div[1]/h1"));
            writer.write(theName.getText());
            System.out.println(theName.getText());
            writer.write("\r\n");
            driver.quit();
            a++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        z++;
        b = Integer.toString(z);
        File file2 = new File("queryNames"+ b + ".txt");
        file2.createNewFile();
        i = 0;
        System.out.println(a);
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("X:\\FilePath"));
        try (BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(file2, true))) {
            while ((names2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i < a) {
                i++;    
                }
                else if (i >= a) {
                writer2.write(names2);
                writer2.write("\r\n");
                i++;
                }
            }
        }
        reader2.close();
    }
    reader.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: May be chrome browser got updated. Try with latest chrome drover version.

Comment: I tried with the newest chrome browser but it still doesn't send any keys. Selenium is also the most updated version.